# Is it idiomatic to say "learn knowledge"?

Tags: idioms

> In this book, the author has introduced many good ways to learn knowledge.

Is it good English to say *learn knowledge*? Is this a common collocation in English?

Comment: Could have been ***earn** knowledge* -- possible typo.

Comment: @Kris - 'To earn knowledge' is an expression with little currency in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not acceptable to use that construction.

One learns information. Once it's learned, it becomes knowledge.

*Knowledge* is awareness, consciousness, or familiarity with something *gained by experience or learning.*

*To learn* is to *acquire knowledge* of or skill in by study, instruction, or experience.

Comment: Thank you very much for this helpful response. Given that "learn knowledge" is not an acceptable construction, could you elaborate on whether "teach knowledge" would be considered unidiomatic as well? Thanks.

Comment: One learns information? I thought "learn information" is not natural English either. We should say "acquire information," "gather information".

Comment: @user43898 "teach knowledge" would not be considered idiomatic in English. We can say "impart knowledge", "pass on knowledge".

Answer (score 2):

"In this book, the author has introduced many good ways to learn knowledge." would be more correctly rendered as "In this book, the author has introduced many good ways to *acquire* knowledge." Alternatively, "In this book, the author has introduced many good ways to learn." would be an expression with the same meaning.

Richard D.